# Erase old lines after ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine

Tags: c#, image, paint, picturebox

I have issues on erasing old lines after ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine and DrawReversibleFrame. I did erase, but screen (usercontrol and picturebox) retains old lines while Mouse_Move. How to erase old lines completely?

I have searched such stuff on stackoverflow, all answers are similar but no functioning for my case.

```
//a picturebox1 on usercontrol.
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //...other code
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(HorizontalSelectionPT1, HorizontalSelectionPT2, Color.Red); //erase old Horizontal line
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(VerticalSelectionPT1, VerticalSelectionPT2, Color.Red); //erase old vertical line
    Point point = PointToScreen(base.Location);
    HorizontalSelectionPT1 = new Point(point.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    HorizontalSelectionPT2 = new Point(point.X + base.Width, Cursor.Position.Y);
    VerticalSelectionPT1 = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, point.Y);
    VerticalSelectionPT2 = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, point.Y + base.Height);
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(HorizontalSelectionPT1, HorizontalSelectionPT2, Color.Red); //Draw new line
    ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(VerticalSelectionPT1, VerticalSelectionPT2, Color.Red); //Draw new line

    //draw selected frame                    
   ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(pbCanvas.RectangleToScreen(rectangle_0), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed); //erase old frame
   rectangle_0.Width = e.X - rectangle_0.X;
   rectangle_0.Height = e.Y - rectangle_0.Y;                    
   ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(pbCanvas.RectangleToScreen(rectangle_0), Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed); //Draw new frame

   //...other codes
}
```

Hardly to capture screenshot, I used Camera.
[image]

Comment: You need to "undo" the previous output in the reverse order it was originally painted.  So DrawReversibleFrame() has to be first.  And you must *not* undo it when the control repainted itself, use the Paint event to know this.

Comment: All reversible lines and frames are painted in Mouse_Move in above codes.

Comment: That comment is very unlikely to help us help you.  Do avoid using ControlPaint.  Instead use the Paint event to draw lines, call Invalidate() in the MouseMove event handler to force a redraw.

Comment: your solution works with a little bit flicker. I put ControlPaint for reversible lines and frames in Paint event.

Comment: BTW, My color is Red, but why the lines are in 'blue'?

Comment: That's how DrawReversibleXxxx works, it uses a XOR operation on the windows surface to make it reversible.  Doing the XOR twice restores the original pixel color.  If the background isn't black then you get a different color.  It also inevitably flickers.  Don't use it, Graphics.DrawLine/DrawRectangle in the Paint event don't have this problem and don't have to be "reversed".

Comment: one small problem is that the reversible lines disappeared when mouse stop to move.

Comment: OK. I used a timer to detect mouse stop then redraw the last lines and frames.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced all ControlPaint.DrawReverseFrame with GDI32 APIs to solve the erase old line problem. Whatever I tried using ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine produced either undesired effect or flickering.

```
   private static int ArgbToRGB(int rgb)
   {
    return ((rgb >> 16 & 0x0000FF) | (rgb & 0x00FF00) | (rgb << 16 & 0xFF0000));
    }

    public enum PenStyles
    {
        PS_OLID = 0,
        PS_DASH = 1,
        PS_DOT = 2,
        PS_DASHDOT = 3,
        PS_DASHDOTDOT = 4,
        PS_NULL = 5,
        PS_INSIDEFRAME = 6,
        PS_USERSTYLE = 7,
        PS_ALTERNATE = 8,
        PS_STYLE_MASK = 0x0000000F,
        PS_ENDCAP_ROUND = 0x00000000,
        PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE = 0x00000100,
        PS_ENDCAP_FLAT = 0x00000200,
        PS_ENDCAP_MASK = 0x00000F00,
        PS_JOIN_ROUND = 0x00000000,
        PS_JOIN_BEVEL = 0x00001000,
        PS_JOIN_MITER = 0x00002000,
        PS_JOIN_MASK = 0x0000F000,
        PS_COSMETIC = 0x00000000,
        PS_GEOMETRIC = 0x00010000
        PS_TYPE_MASK = 0x000F0000
    }
    public enum GDIDrawingMode
    {
        R2_BLACK = 1,
        R2_NOTMERGEPEN = 2,
        R2_MASKNOTPEN = 3,
        R2_NOTCOPYPEN = 4,
        R2_MASKPENNOT = 5,
        R2_NOT = 6,
        R2_XORPEN = 7,
        R2_NOTMASKPEN = 8,
        R2_MASKPEN = 9,
        R2_NOTXORPEN = 10,
        R2_NOP = 11,
        R2_MERGENOTPEN = 12,
        R2_COPYPEN = 13,
        R2_MERGEPENNOT = 14,
        R2_MERGEPEN = 15,
        R2_WHITE = 16            
    }
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "Rectangle", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GDIDrawRectangle(IntPtr hDC, int left, int top, int right, int bottom);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern int SetROP2(IntPtr hDC, int fnDrawMode);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool MoveToEx(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, ref Point p);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool LineTo(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreatePen(int fnPenStyle, int nWidth, int crColor);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObj);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObj);

public static void DrawXORRectangle(Graphics graphics, Color penColor, Rectangle rectangle)
    {            
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr hPen = CreatePen((int)PenStyles.PS_DOT, 1, ArgbToRGB(penColor.ToArgb()));
        IntPtr hOldPen = SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
        SetROP2(hDC, (int)GDIDrawingMode.R2_NOTXORPEN);
        GDIDrawRectangle(hDC, rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom);
        SelectObject(hDC, hOldPen);
        DeleteObject(hPen);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
    }
```

[image]